# Atlas text search using mongoose is returning an empty array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to create an autocompleted form field. I have set up a search index in Atlas correctly. I can test this by running the following command in the MongoDB playground (VSCode extension):

```
use("Development");
db;
db.PlcMarketCaps.aggregate([
    {
        $search: {
            index: "default",
            autocomplete: {
                query: "SCOT",
                path: "companyName",
                fuzzy: { maxEdits: 1 }
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

This works as expected. However, when I incorporate the same command inside my project which uses mongoose it will only ever return an empty array. Here is the code I am using:

```
export async function searchPlcCompanies(query: string): Promise<string[] | undefined> {
    return PlcMarketCap.aggregate()
        .search({
            index: "default",
            autocomplete: {
                query: `${query}`,
                path: "companyName",
                fuzzy: { maxEdits: 1 }
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            return response;
        })
        .catch((error: Error) => {
            throw error;
        });
}
```

I have also tried:

```
export async function searchPlcCompanies(query: string): Promise<string[] | undefined> {
    return PlcMarketCap.aggregate()
        $search: {
            autocomplete: {
                query: `${query}`,
                path: "companyName",
                fuzzy: {
                    maxEdits: 2,
                    prefixLength: 3
                }
            }
       }
}
```

The debugger shows me that the function receives the correct query string. The only difference between this and the MongoDB playground command, is the it goes through mongoose first. Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you create a search index? Login to atlas -> yourCollection -> tab Collections -> Search Indexes -> Create Search Index

Comment: Yes, I have created a search index, I can test it is working properly because the search functionality works fine with the MongoDB playground.

Comment: @JamesGreenaway did you somehow fix the issue? I am having the same problem